# Change action value using set attribute (DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have an HTML file which contains 2 forms inside a class called column.

```
 <div class="column">

       <form  action="" method="post" >              
  
       <button type="submit" class="button">ON</button>
                                                    
       </form>
                               
        
      <form action =""  method="post" > 
                                    
      <button type="submit" class="button2">OFF</button>
                                   
      </form>

</div>
```

I can change headers etc (not included in this code) inside the 2 forms using the method i have used below. However,  i dont know why im not able to change the "action" value using the same principle.

GOAL : Im wondering how i can select the action inside the form and do a set attribute

What i tried

```
const BOX = document.querySelectorAll('.column');  //selects the entire class

const child1 = BOX[0].querySelectorAll('form');  //selects all forms

const formchild = child1[0].querySelector('p :nth-child(2)');  // selects form 1
formchild.setAttribute('action', 'http://xxxxxx//'); 

const formchild2 = child1[1].querySelector('p :nth-child(1)'); // selects form 2
formchild2.setAttribute('action', 'http://xxxxxx//');
```

Comment: you can try this, it might solve your question to set the action at runtime with javascript: https://html.form.guide/html-form/form-action-using-javascript-function/

Answer (score 0):

element.querySelectorAll returns an array: Therefore

```
const BOX = document.querySelectorAll('.column');  //selects the entire class
// changed it here 
const child1 = BOX[0].querySelectorAll('form');  //selects all forms

let formchild1 = child1[0].querySelector('p :nth-child(2)');  // selects form 1 
// WHAT IS THIS DOWN HERE, please give additional info
formchild1.setAttribute('action', 'http://xxxxxx//'); 

let formchild2 = child1[1].querySelector('p :nth-child(1)'); // selects form 2
formchild2.setAttribute('action', 'http://xxxxxx//');
```

should work!

Comment: im so sorry , my code already had that parameter before. i made a typo. i made a typo for the frmchld as well.  i have updated the entire code. Thankss..

Comment: did this help you? If yes, please upvote and mark as answered!

Comment: Hey, i already had that in my code before itself. But when i wrote it here i made that mistakes. Even with this code it doesn not work. Thank you

Comment: Umm so you've got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

At last i found a solution. I put an id for the forms and its starting to work

const chld1 = BOX_1[0].querySelector('#form1');
chld1.setAttribute('action','http://')

const chld2 = BOX_1[0].querySelector('#form2');
chld2.setAttribute('action','http://')